# AWS database tokens refreshing during upload causeing errors

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an activity in android studio that uploads a record to the AWS DB as follows:

```
final Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
final AWSConfiguration awsConfig = new AWSConfiguration(appContext);
final IdentityManager identityManager = new IdentityManager(appContext, awsConfig);
IdentityManager.setDefaultIdentityManager(identityManager);
identityManager.doStartupAuth(activity, new StartupAuthResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(StartupAuthResult startupAuthResult) {
        // User identity is ready as unauthenticated
        // user or previously signed-in user.
    }
});

final AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = identityManager.getCredentialsProvider();
AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);

this.dynamoDBMapper = DynamoDBMapper.builder()
    .dynamoDBClient(dynamoDBClient)
    .awsConfiguration(awsConfig)
    .build();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Show Progress:", "Start saving an item");

        dynamoDBMapper.save(poll);

        Log.d("Show Progress:", "Saved an item");
    }
}).start();
```

It works fine on the first upload however when I select an image from the phone (image selector launches) then call upload again it throws an error.

The information I'm getting from the console which points to the root of the issue is as follows...

When the upload succeeds:

```
D/IdentityManager: Starting up authentication...
D/IdentityManager: Got user ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
D/Show Progress:: Start saving an item
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/Show Progress:: Saved an item
```

When upload fails

```
D/IdentityManager: Starting up authentication...
D/IdentityManager: Got user ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
D/Show Progress:: Start saving an item
D/AWSRefreshingCognitoIdentityProvider: Refreshing token...
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
E/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: Failure to get credentials
```

For some reason after "select image" when upload is called the identityProvider refreshes the tokens and so fails to retrieve the credentials. Is there a way to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few  days of pulling my hair out finally found a solution.

Reconstructed the Credentials provider as follows and removed the identity manager in it's entirety.

```
    final Context appContext = activity;
    final AWSConfiguration awsConfig = new AWSConfiguration(appContext);

    final CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsprovider1 = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(activity, awsConfig);
```

This didn't fix the problem fully, I had to also change the refreshThreshold:

```
    credentialsprovider1.setRefreshThreshold(10);
```